# How can I add zero's in empty slots in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

How can I add zero's in empty slots in a list in python?

for example

```
list_1 = ['2','4',' ','3',' ','1',' ']
```

output I want:

```
 ['2','4','0','3','0','1','0']
```

Comment: Those slots are not 'empty', the are a single space character. Will that always be true?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list comprehension that will do it:

```py
list_1 = ['0' if i.strip() == '' else i for i in list_1]
```

Comment: Careful, the OP's list has spaces not empty lists. This solution doesn't work for the posted input.

Comment: Adding another solution, ``['0' if not i.strip() else i for i in list_1]``

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this

```
list_1 = ['2','4','','3','','1','']
for i in list_1:
    if i =="":
        list_1[list_1.index(i)] = 0
print(list_1)
```